# Backbone and Require how to add Qunit

Tags: backbone.js, require, qunit

I'm using Backbone and Require.js. Everything works great but, I would like to add some unit tests to my application. I decided use Qunit.js.

In my **main.js** file I create new object `EventsView`:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery:                 'libs/jquery',
    underscore:             'libs/underscore',
    backbone:               'libs/backbone',
    qunit:                  'test/libs/qunit-1.10.0
    }
 });
 require(['view/eventsView', 
          'test/eventsView_test', 
          'test/eventView_test' ], function(EventsView){
           var events = new EventsView; //here I create first object my View
 });
```

In **eventsView.js** `initialize` I render the main view

```
  define(['jquery',
          'backbone',
          'underscore',
          'collection/eventC',
          'model/eventM',
          'view/eventView'], function($, Backbone,_,EventC,EventM, EventView,){

 var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".contener"),     
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
     },
     ....//other functions
    });
     return EventsView;
 });
```

So now I need to call functions from this view in other file **eventsView_test.js**.
I can't do it like this because the View will be rendered again:

```
  define(['jquery','qunit','view/eventsView'], function($,qunit,EventsView){
    //var eventsView = new EventsView(); // I can't create object here 

    test( "first_test_func", function() {
        var result = eventsView.first_test_func(2,2);
        equal( result, 4, "2 square equals 4" );
    });
```

What should I do?  Do I need some kind of singleton or something else?

Comment: hmmm and maybe when in constructor - initialize() I'll create condition: if(view.contener doesn't exist) render it
Do You think this is correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fantastic question, and one that I see all the time.

I actually solved this by creating what I dubbed a "bootstrap" paradigm, but call it whatever you want.  The key is that the Backbone view does not render itself, but instead whomever consumes it is responsible for that.  You'll run into issues with fetch() and the like, so thankfully this solves that too.

**The goal: Don't unit test render and just skip it all together!**

### Your view becomes something like this:

```
require(function () {
    var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        // initialize is executed on new, just as you found
        initialize: function (options) {
            _.bindAll(this);

            // Create models, initialize properties, and bind to events here.
            // Basically only do __UNEXPENSIVE__, non-dom-changing things that
            // you don't care get executed a lot.                

            this.someCollection = new Backbone.Collection();
            this.someCollection.on('add', this.onSomeCollectionAdd);
        },

        // bootstrap is for server-side operations that you don't want executed
        // by every single test.
        bootstrap: function () {
            this.someCollection.fetch().done(this.render);
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(...);
        },

        first_test_func: function () {

        }
    });

    return view;
});
```

### How this would be consumed in your app:

```
require(['viewpath'], function (myView) {
    var instance = new myView({ el: $('#something') });
    instance.bootstrap(); //triggers fetch, or if no fetch needed, just render
});
```

### This can now be unit tested without worry.

```
define(['jquery','qunit','view/eventsView'], function($,qunit,EventsView){

    test( "first_test_func", function() {
        // Now this line won't call the server, or render.
        // You can isolate/test what you want.
        var eventsView = new EventsView();
        var result = eventsView.first_test_func(2,2);
        equal( result, 4, "2 square equals 4" );
    });
});
```

### Use SinonJS

I strongly recommend checking out [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/).  It's amazing for unit testing JavaScript, particularly Backbone implementations due to its powerful mocking which can be used from preventing the rendering and server calls (`fetch`, `save`, etc) from actually hitting the server while still allowing you to assert they got called.

Comment: thank You :). This is very helpful answer.
I'll try this SinonJS :)