# How to unit test instantiated object: qUnit/sonar/phantomJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, sonarqube, phantomjs, qunit

Using qUnit to do unit test and sonar to do code coverage.

Does anyone know how to test so I can cover instantiated object:
Given I initialize this object on a different file

```
var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

Should I also test:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Alerts suck.");
    }
});
```

which is on a different file? and has its own test.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone and Require how to add Qunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991065/backbone-and-require-how-to-add-qunit)