# How to use qunit in a backbone app

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, qunit

I'm currently working on an app that is built from Backbone.js, with Require.js to load dependencies. I had hoped to be able to load QUnit and have a page where the user can simply load the page and it will dynamically run unit tests. However, I've hit a snag. Whenever I load the page, the tests work, but if I navigate away from the page and then come back, QUnit breaks with the following error:
`Uncaught Error: pushFailure() assertion outside test context,`

Below is the code that I am currently working with. My real question is this: With my current Backbone.js layout, is it feasible to use QUnit in the way I want, or should I scrap this feature?

When the page loads, the parent view `service_test.view.js` is rendered:

```
define(['backbone', 'hgn', 'statemachine_test_view'],
function (Backbone, hgn, StateMachineTest) {
    var DynamicTest = Backbone.View.extend({
        // This is the main element of the application, it is what is cleared and populated for each page
        el: $(".overwatch_container"),
        // Build the Statemachine test view (statemachine_test.view.js)
        statemachine_view: new StateMachineTest(),

        render: function (data) {
            // Empty out anything that's in the container already
            this.$el.empty();

            // Contain the 'this' reference, so it can be used throughout
            var that = this;

            // Pull in and populate the hogan template for the main parent elements
            require(['hgn!templates/service_test.template.hogan'], function (tmpl) {
                // JSON object with all of thd page's information to pass to the templates
                resultset = {
                            "service_type": data.service_type
                };

                // Render the template with the given information, and then build child views
                if( that.$el.html( tmpl.render( resultset ) ) )
                {
                    // Build the child view
                    that.statemachine_view.render();
                }
            });

        },

        close: function () {
            $(this.$el).empty();
            return this;
        }

    });

    // Return the view object, so it can be utilized when this script is require'd
    return DynamicTest;
});
```

statemachine_test.view.js is where StateMachineTest is created:

```
define(['backbone', 'hgn'],
function (Backbone, hgn) {
    var StateMachineTest = Backbone.View.extend({

        render: function (options) {
            // Dynamically set the element associated with this view, as it is not instantiated when this is first included by Require.js
            this.setElement( $(".test_content") );

            // Contain the 'this' reference, so it can be used throughout
            var that = this;

            require(['hgn!templates/qunit_base.template.hogan'], function (tmpl) {
                // JSON object with all of thd page's information to pass to the templates

                // Render the template with the given information, and then build child views
                if( that.$el.html(tmpl.render()) )
                {

                    // Once the template has been rendered, load the qUnit test script
                    // 'statemachine_dynamic' = statemachine_dynamic.test.js
                    require(['QUnit', 'statemachine_dynamic'], function(QUnit, statemachine) {
                        statemachine.run();

                        QUnit.load();
                        QUnit.start(); //THIS IS THE LINE THE ERROR POINTS TO

                        QUnit.done( function (details) {
                            _.each($("#qunit-tests li").children("a"), function (child) {
                                $(child).attr("href", function (index, attr) {
                                    return attr+window.location.hash;
                                });
                            });

                        });

                    });
                }
            });

        },

    });

    return StateMachineTest;
});
```

And this is my actual test script, statemachine_dynamic.test.js:

```
define([], function () {
    var run = function() {
        module("Statemachine Testing");
        test( "Test 1", function() {
            var value = "hello";
            equal( value, "hello", "We expect value to be hello" );
        });
        test( "Test 2", function() {
            var value = "hello";
            equal( value, "hello", "We expect value to be hello" );
        });
        test( "Test 3", function() {
            var value = "hello";
            equal( value, "hello", "We expect value to be hello" );
        });
    };
    return {run: run};
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone and Require how to add Qunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991065/backbone-and-require-how-to-add-qunit)

Answer (score 1):

`Qunit.start()` doesn't start the tests. `start()` is for async testing if you comment it out your test will probably be run aswel altough i do not know require.js